# How to make autosize(height) UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

Please tell me how to make a cell to automatically change the height depending on the number of rows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **iOS8** it will be automatically managed for you

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/24/ios8-day-by-day-day-5-auto-sizing-table-view-cells

In **iOS7/6** you can use autolayout to do this. You can create your cell setting up the constraints you need. In your case you can attach the label to the top,bottom, trailing and leading of the superview.

In the `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you can use `[cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];` to get the minimum size of the cell. For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = self.layoutTableViewCell;

    [cell configureWithText:text];

    CGSize layoutSize =  [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    return layoutSize.height;
}
```

Remember to avoid to set width and height constraints to the UILabel, it will resize automatically to fit the content.

You can create the `self.layoutTableViewCell` in the viewDidLoad using:

```
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CustomCellNibName bundle:nil];
    self.layoutTableViewCell = [[cellNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

OT: I think is matter of personal taste. Personally i started to use always UICollectionViews, just to reuse more code and have more flexibility if in the future i need to customise layout behaviours.

Comment: The OP has a `UITableView`, not a `UICollectionView`. The Shinobi Controls link is appreciated though.

Comment: @LucaBartoletti I added code: `UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:CustomCellNibName bundle:nil];
    self.layoutTableViewCell = [[cellNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`  in viewDidLoad but there was an error `Property ‘layoutTableViewCell’ not found on object of type ‘MyTableViewController *'`

Comment: Because you need to create a property for that

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) YourCustomCellType *layoutTableViewCell;

Comment: You could be call `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]` if you add your subviews to contentView inside cell